# how can i load the data into a local csv file from a select query in red shift and automate the process for everyday scheduling.?

Tags: file, amazon-redshift, job-scheduling

how can we load the data into a local csv file(should not be s3 bucket) from a select query in red shift and  automate the process for everyday scheduling.?

please share the link for reference.

Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via any SQL client.

Here is the reference link: https://dwgeek.com/export-redshift-table-data-local-csv-format.html/

Schedule the export method in your local.

**Suggestions:**

- The CSV file does not handle the special characters.
- It may break your data load.
- Unload with quotes (to S3) would be the best choice. You can schedule it in your local.